# Error on IIS App Pools after upgrading from Windows Server 2013 to Windows Server 2016 (or Win 8.1 to Win 10)

Tags: windows, iis, windows-10

After upgrading my Windows installation from 8.1 to 10, a number of App Pools were failing to start, showing the following entries in the Event Viewer:

Application:

```
Source: IIS-W3SVC-WP
Event ID: 2307
The worker process for application pool '<app pool name>' encountered an error 'Cannot read configuration file' trying to read configuration data from file '\\?\<EMPTY>', line number '0'. The data field contains the error code.
```

System:

```
Source: WAS
Event ID: 5189
The Windows Process Activation Service failed to generate an application pool config file for application pool '<app pool name>'. The error type is '5'. To resolve this issue, please ensure that the applicationhost.config file is correct and recommit the last configuration changes made. The data field contains the error number.

Source: WAS
Event ID: 5203
A process serving application pool '<app pool name>' reported a failure trying to read configuration during startup. The process id was '4120'.  Please check the Application Event Log for further event messages logged by the worker process on the specific error.  The data field contains the error number.
```

I've found a lot of people saying to reinstall IIS/WAS but, even after doing that, the error persisted.

For some reason, recreating the App Pool with another name would fix the error but I didn't want to keep it that way. After renaming the App Pool back to the original name, it started to fail again.

Comment: I really didn't get how this question is off-topic. The issue is obviously technical, it's  about server technologies, and it's about supported software and hardware. Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using the excellent Process Monitor to analyze what files the *Windows Process Activation Service* was trying to read/create, I found these files and directories in `C:\inetpub\temp\apppools` that the Windows Upgrade process probably messed up with. I deleted those old files and directories and restarted the App Pools.

Everything is working fine now!

Comment: You should accept this as answer if it solved the issue